# IE error 'var' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I have in my application an autocomplete input field. When jsp with this autocomplete input field opens I get error `'names' is undefined` in line `<body onload="getNames(names)">`. This happens only in IE8,7,9. In Chrome and Firefox everything is fine. In controller I fetch user's names and surnames and write them in one string seperated with `$` and then I send that string `allUsersRoleUserAC` to jsp. Method getNames(names) splits that string and put them to var `tags`.

Here is jsp code:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Admin page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/css/jquery-ui.css") %>" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/css/DOMAlert.css") %>" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/JavaScript/DOMAlert.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/JavaScript/jquery-1.8.2.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/JavaScript/jquery-ui.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tags = new Array();
function getNames(names){
    tags = names.value.split('$');
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="getNames(names)" >

    <form action="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/admin/deleteUser.html") %>" method="post">
        <input id="names" type="hidden" value="${ requestScope['allUsersRoleUserAC'] }" />
        <input name="korisnik" class="userSelectDeleteUser" value="ime prezime" onclick="this.value=''" id="autocomplete" />
        <input class="izbrisiKorisnikaButtonPosition" id="buttonRightPart" type="button" value="Izbriši" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
                    return matcher.test( item );
                }) );
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java/JSP.  Figure how to do it using JavaScript/HTML & that logic should be easy to use in the JSP.

Comment: What do you expect `names` to be? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Not sure that I understand you. I use javascript to this and it works fine in firefox but in IE it doesn't work. Do you know if I can do something to correct this to work in IE or some workaround?

Comment: Actually this was originally an IE-only thing. Can't believe it doesn't work any more… [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

Comment: names is input field with id="names"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onload="getNames(names)"
```

What is the world is `names`? You need to use getElementById to reference an element. You should not reference an element by an id directly.

```
onload="getNames(document.getElementById('names'));"
```

Answer (score 1):

`names` is in fact undefined.  Other browsers will just be passing the undefined value, whereas IE won't let you do that.

If you want to get the `names` element then you can use

```
document.getElementById('names')
```

I would advise putting that inside the onLoad function rather than passing it as a parameter though, to separate the logic out from the markup.

Answer (score 1):

`onload="getNames($("#names").val())"`

or non jQuery

`onload="getNames(document.getElementById('names').value)"`

Comment: uh, there is definitely no jQuery loaded on this page.

Comment: oh yeah... I saw ` $( "#autocomplete" )` and got excited

Comment: I use jQuery but didn't paste all that to simplify